# Does someone know what this error is?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, exchange-server

When I run my ASP.net app I get this error:

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 
>   Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Exchange' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 06:  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
>
> Line 07:  using System.Data.OleDb;
>
> Line 08:  using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data; // error
>
> Line 09:  using System.Net;
>
> Line 10:  using System.Data.SqlClient;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll as a reference to your project?

You'll have to have the Exchange Webservices Managed API installed on your box and the DLL can be found in c:\program files\microsoft\exchange\web services\1.0

You can download the API [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c3342fb3-fbcc-4127-becf-872c746840e1).

Comment: What do you mean by you need to have EWS MAPI installed on your box?

Answer (score 1):

Switch Target framework from .NET Framework 4 Client Profile to .Net Framework 4

Comment: It may not be applicable for web applications but Check out this post and see if it helps http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/26f1a426-f42d-4bab-8245-1a77c3f09251

Answer (score 0):

The error itself suggests you might be missing an assembly reference.

From Visual Studio, click Add Reference and add a reference to the assembly that contains Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.

Comment: I've added the reference, I did this by the steps you describe!